# Put request failing with Alamofire 2.0

Tags: swift, rest, alamofire

I have recently upgraded to `Alamofire 2.0`, and now my Put request is failing with a 400 error, when it was previously working properly. I perform the call with the code:

```
Alamofire.request(Router.Put(query: url, params: params, encoding: .JSON))
    .validate()
    .responseJSON() {
        (request, response, result) in

        print("request: \(request)")
        print("response: \(response)")
        print("result: \(result)")

        switch result {
        case .Success(_):
            // success
        case .Failure(let data, _):
            // error occured
        }
}
```

and my custom Router class:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {

    case Get(query: String, params: [String: AnyObject]?)
    case Post(query: String, params: [String: AnyObject]?)
    case Put(query: String, params: [String: AnyObject]?, encoding: ParameterEncoding)
    case Delete(query: String, params: [String: AnyObject]?)

    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
        var encodeMethod: Alamofire.ParameterEncoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

        // Default to GET
        var httpMethod: String = Alamofire.Method.GET.rawValue

        let (path, parameters): (String, [String: AnyObject]?) = {
            switch self {
            case .Get(let query, let params):
                // Set the request call
                httpMethod = Alamofire.Method.GET.rawValue
                // Return the query
                return (query, params)
            case .Post(let query, let params):
                // Set the request call
                httpMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
                // Return the query
                return (query, params)
            case .Put(let query, let params, let encoding):
                // Set the request call
                httpMethod = Alamofire.Method.PUT.rawValue
                // Set the encoding
                encodeMethod = encoding
                // Return the query
                return (query, params)
            case .Delete(let query, let params):
                // Set the request call
                httpMethod = Alamofire.Method.DELETE.rawValue
                // Return the query
                return (query, params)
            }
        }()

        // Create the URL Request
        let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: Globals.BASE_URL + path)!)
        // set header fields
        if let key = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(Globals.NS_KEY_SESSION) {
            URLRequest.setValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-XX-API")
        }
        // Add user agent
        if let userAgent = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(Globals.NS_KEY_USER_AGENT) {
        URLRequest.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        }

        // Set the HTTP method
        URLRequest.HTTPMethod = httpMethod

        URLRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

        return encodeMethod.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    }
}
```

Instead of the call being a success, the response is:

```
response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fcee15b34d0> { URL: https://apiurl } { status code: 400, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
"Content-Length" = 26;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Tue, 15 Sep 2015 15:33:50 GMT";
Expires = "-1";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
} })
```

I looked into the problem and on the server side, `Content-Type` is coming in as blank for the request, when it should be coming in as `application/json`. The `Content-Type` should automatically get added when there is body data in the request. I have the params set:

```
// Save the profile
var params: [String: AnyObject] = ["indexPhoto": userProfile.indexPhoto,
    "dob": df.stringFromDate(userProfile.dob) as NSString,
    "identAs": userProfile.identAs]
// Add manually since creating the dictionary all at once is too much for swift to handle
params.updateValue(String(format:"%.2f", userProfile.heightIn), forKey: "heightIn")
params.updateValue(String(format:"%.2f", userProfile.weightLbs), forKey: "weightLbs")
params.updateValue(userProfile.eyes, forKey: "eyes")
params.updateValue(userProfile.hair, forKey: "hair")
...
```

Is there something I could be missing with this? Before I upgraded to `Alamofire 2.0` this call was working just fine.

Comment: Could you post the `debugPrint` output of the `Request` you are creating with `Alamofire.request` call? That would certainly help. Also, you should try to use that cURL to see if you can hit your server as expected.

Comment: $ curl -i \
     -X PUT \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iOS 9.1; en_US; [en]) BC/2.0.0.40" \
     -H "X-XX-API: myApp x-XX-api value” \
     -H "Accept-Language: en-US;q=1.0" \
     -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,compress;q=0.5" \
     -H "User-Agent: myAppUserAgent (40; OS Version 9.1 (Build 13B5110e))" \
     -d "{\"hShowCity\":true,\"langs\":\"168|169\", ... \"dob\":\"1982-11-18T00:00:00\"}" \
     "https://myAppApi/member/profile/edit"

Comment: I used `debugDescription` because `Request` didn't have `debugPrint`. I cut out some of the parameters because with all of them in there, the comment was too long to post.

This API is already in production, so I know the endpoint does work. I did notice there are two `User-Agent` values.

Comment: @cnoon we ended up finding out what the error was. Thanks for the help with using the 'debugDescription'. The person who works on the server side required a variable which was supposed to be depricated. It's not hurting anything, but how can we replace the 'User-Agent' instead of having a second header value?

Comment: You can override the `User-Agent` header by setting it on the `Request` (the request headers override the configuration) or by not setting it on the `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: You're missing a lot of convenience in your Router enum. You shouldn't be passing in a HTTP type and url to it you should be doing something like... `Router.CreateUser(name: String)` or something. The `Router` is there to take the different routes and turn them into url requests.

Comment: Here is an example of the Router I use... https://gist.github.com/oliverfoggin/119baa971678f8c04e293874b2d4c5ab

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a different way but I fixed the same issue by sending empty params instead of nil. I don't use any parameters when using .PUT and because of that server doesn't know how to encode request and response (even if I explicitly set content type inside header, I receive blank content type on the server) so my solution was sending empty params like in the code below. Hope it helps someone.

```
var url = https://api.mysite.com/v1/issue/369613/delete

let params = ["":""]

let headers = NetworkConnection.addAuthorizationHeader(token, tokenType: tokenType)
manager.request(.PUT, url, parameters: params, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let JSONdata = response.result.value {
                print("JSONdata: \(JSONdata)")
            }
}
```